# To show a set is a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G $ be a subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$. Define $H=\{A\in G :\exists$ a continuous function $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow G$ such that $\phi(0)=A   \&   \phi(1)=I_{n\times n}\}$ .

Is $H$ a normal subgroup of G?

Answer: $H$ is non empty as the constant function $\phi:[0,1]\rightarrow G$ defined by $\phi(x)=I \forall x $ is continuous.But how to show existence of $A.B $ for $A,B \in H$ and its inverse ?

Comment: Consider $t \mapsto B \phi(t)B^{-1}$.

Comment: Are you having difficult with showing it is a subgroup or the normal part?

Comment: A.B is done as we can have the product of two continuous functions f and g we have got in case of A & B.But how to show inverse

Comment: if f is a cont. func.  such that f(0)=A & f(1)=I and similarly for B we have g then fg(0)=f(0).g(0)=A.B and fg(1)=I .is it not true sir?

Comment: can you  please elaborate? i did not get you

Comment: My apologies, I was wrong about the product. For the inverse, consider $f(t)= A^{-1} \phi(1-t)$, where $\phi$ is the function for $A$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17941/discussion-between-learning-maths-and-copper-hat).